# Why is the mouse wheel scrolling speed faster in qmlscene?

Tags: qt, qml

`main.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 400
    title: "List"

    ListView {
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height

        model: 50

        delegate: Item {
            width: if (parent) parent.width
            height: 50

            Rectangle {
                width: parent.width
                height: 50

                Text {
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    text: "Text"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qt/qml/main/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(qml-list LANGUAGES CXX)

find_package(Qt6 6.2 COMPONENTS Quick Gui REQUIRED)

qt_standard_project_setup(REQUIRES 6.5)

find_package(Qt6 6.2 COMPONENTS Quick Gui REQUIRED)

qt_add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Qt6::Gui Qt6::Quick)

qt_add_qml_module(${PROJECT_NAME}
    URI main
    QML_FILES
        main.qml
)
```

Qt 6.6.0, Linux Manjaro KDE.

In the app the scrolling with the mouse is painfully slow. But when launching `qmlscene main.qml` the scrolling is fast.

How to make it scroll like in qmlscene?

Comment: One way to investigate would be to look at qmlscene sources

Comment: @hyde I've tried that yesterday. Turns out that I was using `qmlscene` from Qt5. The `qmlscene6` has the slowness problem. It's probably a Qt6 bug.

Comment: You have `2.15` versions in your imports. Would it help if you removed the version numbers to make it more Qt6.x compliant? Also, how about changing your `width` property to `width: ListView.view.width` ?

Comment: Another difference between Qt5.x and Qt6.x is the rendering engine change. Try setting the `QSG_RHI_BACKEND` environment variable to `opengl`. For further information, consult https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-visualcanvas-scenegraph-renderer.html#rendering-via-the-qt-rendering-hardware-interface